# Injecting javascript into other websites

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am trying to build a diagnostic overlay tool for a web app I'm working on. It works great as a chrome extension but I would like to investigate ways to do it without having to use the extension.

Ideally, I'd open an iframe and inject my .js file into it. Obviously this isn't possible with security restrictions.

My alternate method was to set up a 'proxy' that injected the js dynamically (as in, downloaded the URL requested, and served it back up). This seems complicated to get right and as the extension depends on the site working correctly to overlay on the correct elements, wouldn't look good if some strange reference was missed or link was not rewritten.

Can anyone think of any alternate approaches? The JS basically adds a small overlay box on things showing various analytics stats.

Thanks!
Martin

Comment: Do you have admin access to the hosting website?

Comment: The Same Origin Policy prevents you from injecting anything into an Iframe that is from a different domain. You need a hook in the original page to pull-in your code. You can't push it in.

Comment: How will clients use it if it's not an extension? Which clients are you targetting with this feature? You mentionned a proxy so I expect you to have total control over your user's network...?

Comment: The users could have admin access but I would rather not require they add the script.

By proxy I meant a web proxy, as in the navigate to http://www.mysite.com/?starturl=www.google.com and in this example, the server would load the content from google, and inser the JS reference before rendering it to the client. All links would have to be rewritten to point at that link though, to avoid them losing the script when navigating away.

Comment: As it seems, you'll need to use an Extension